# Python Selenium can't find elements on webpage collapse/expand section (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

I am new to selenium in Python. I was trying to to get the opening hours for each part of a supermarket(store/petrol station/pharmacy/cafe) from its website https://my.morrisons.com/storefinder/8 . The info only shows up when each section is selected(expanded).

I saw the details are available in the Chrome developer tool, but I could not parse them using Beautifulsoup or urllib. I wasn't sure if it was because it was generated dynamically by Javascript.

I did some research and tried to use selenium with different methods such as find_element_by_xpath and find_element_by_link, however, none of them could help me locate those collapse section or the actual opening hour info.

Could someone please give me some guidance on how to solve this issue? Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Working with Selenium, you should waiting for page loading, then find panels and click on it and grab hours.
On JS this code is working for me (assume browser is selenium web driver and requested page is loaded)

```
await browser.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css('.according-markers.ng-scope')));
var panels = await browser.findElements(By.css('.according-markers.ng-scope'));
for(let panel of panels){
    await panel.findElement(By.css('a')).click();
    let hoursEl = await panel.findElements(By.css('span.ng-binding'));
    let hours = await Promise.all(hoursEl.map(function(el) { return el.getText()}));
    console.log(hours);
}
```

Comment: Not sure what the question is. Please clarify.

Comment: I think that question is why Selenium not found elements of collapsed sections, and I give tested code on Selenium with JavaScript. I think problem was in not awaiting for Selenium loading page or collapsed section

Comment: @EkaterinaPozdnyakova I followed your JS code and got it worked in Python. Thank you very much for your help!!